# Snakemake 200000 job submission

Tags: snakemake

I have 200000 fasta sequences. I am doing GATK to call variants and created a wildcard for every sequence. Now I would like to submit 200000 jobs using snakemake. Will this cause a problem to cluster? Is there a way to submit jobs in a set of 10-20?

Comment: `--jobs` is what you are looking for. You may also benefit from [using `--batch`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#dealing-with-very-large-workflows).

Comment: I am actually already using -j 50 something like this...but still after I run the job the cluster had a problem.

Comment: I don't know... But it seems to me 200k jobs is a lot however you turn it and presumably most of them are on tiny fasta sequences. I would consider writing a simple script that groups sequences in a few tens of batches to be submitted to GATK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it might take some time to calculate the DAG, but I have been told the DAG calculation recently has been greatly improved. Anyways, it might be wise to [split up in batches](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#dealing-with-very-large-workflows).

Most clusters won't allow you to submit more than X jobs at the same time, usually in the range of 100-1000. I believe the documentation is not fully correct, but when using `--cluster` cluster I believe the `--jobs` argument controls the number of active/submitted jobs at the same time, so by using `snakemake --jobs 20 --cluster "myclustercommand"` you should be able to control this. Know that this control the number of **submitted** jobs, not active jobs. It might be that all your jobs are in the queue, so probably best to check in with your cluster administrator and ask what the maximum number of submitted jobs is, and get as close to that number.